# Get Rid of Global Variables in Code of create_function() Used in spl_autoload_register() in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, syntax, global-variables

I'm trying to get rid of the global variables in the following custom function. What it does is to register classes automatically defined in the files in the classes directory and redefine them as an extended class with a specified suffix.

```
autoload_classes();
print_r(get_declared_classes());   

function autoload_classes() {
    global $class_files, $dirpath;
    $dirpath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/';
    $class_files = array_map(create_function( '$a', 'return basename($a, ".php");' ), glob($dirpath . '*.php'));
    spl_autoload_register(
        create_function('$class_name', '
            global $class_files, $dirpath;
            if (in_array($class_name, $class_files)) 
                include($dirpath . $class_name . ".php");' )
    );

    foreach ($class_files as $class_name) {
        $class_name_alpha = $class_name . "_alpha";
        eval("class $class_name_alpha extends $class_name {};");    
    }
}
```

I tried like this but it causes an error. How can I fix it?

```
autoload_classes();
print_r(get_declared_classes());   

function autoload_classes() {

    $dirpath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/';
    $class_files = array_map(create_function( '$a', 'return basename($a, ".php");' ), glob($dirpath . '*.php'));
    spl_autoload_register(
        create_function('$class_name', '        
            if (in_array($class_name, ' . var_export($class_files, true) . ')) 
                include(' . $dirpath . ' . $class_name . ".php");
        ')
    );

    foreach ($class_files as $class_name) {
        $class_name_alpha = $class_name . "_alpha";
        eval("class $class_name_alpha extends $class_name {};");    
    }
}
```

Some of my servers are below PHP v5.3 so closures cannot be used. Thanks for your info.

Comment: Closures are the correct answer here. You mention that some of your servers are not on PHP 5.3. It's worth pointing out that PHP 5.2 was declared end-of-life nearly two years ago now, and hasn't had any security patches since then. It's badly out of date and likely to be insecure. You **really** need to upgrade.

Comment: Oh really... I was told the same thing in the previous question I posted. Thanks for the info. On the other hand, what if I distribute a script using this code? Should I tell my users not to use PHP v5.2 or below? You may say do not to use create_function() and define another function for sql_autoload_register() but I feel it being sloppy to have an extra function when it can be only one.

Comment: btw - in any case, I would also recommend avoiding `eval()` and `create_function()`, because code generated using them is impossible to work with in a debugger. I know I couldn't work without xdebug. (not to mention the fact that eval'd code runs ten times slower than native php code).

Comment: Most new PHP code being released these days is for 5.3 and above only. Certainly all the major frameworks have standardised on 5.3. None of the major Linux distributions supply 5.2 in their supoprted versions, so if you're on 5.2 the odds are you're also on an out-of-date version of the OS, along with all the security issues that implies.  Any web hosting company that is still only offering 5.2 should be avoided, because they clearly don't take security seriously if they haven't bothered updating for two years.

Comment: I see. Indeed, 'hard to debug' and 'ten times slower' are something should be avoided. Does `create_function()` have the same speed issue as `eval()`?

Comment: yes it does -- anywhere that you have PHP code generated in a string will have the same issues.

Comment: That's something I didn't know about. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this worked. I thought `var_export()` is only necessary for arrays but variables containing strings also needed it.

```
autoload_classes();
print_r(get_declared_classes());   

function autoload_classes() {

    $dirpath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/';
    $class_files = array_map(create_function( '$a', 'return basename($a, ".php");' ), glob($dirpath . '*.php'));
    spl_autoload_register(
        create_function('$class_name', '        
            if (in_array($class_name, ' . var_export($class_files, true) . ')) 
                include(' . var_export($dirpath, true) . ' . $class_name . ".php");
        ')
    );

    foreach ($class_files as $class_name) {
        $class_name_alpha = $class_name . "_alpha";
        eval("class $class_name_alpha extends $class_name {};");    
    }
}
```